# How do I retrieve location data from javascript using Ajax $_POST in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, location

I can't get the following code to work in PHP. I want to retrieve the users location then send it to my php script for further processing on the server. The Php won't retrieve the data.

Edited:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<script>

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
  } else {
  alert('Geolocation is required for this page, but your browser doesn&apos;t support it. Try it with a browser that does, such as Opera 10.60.');
}

function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var long = position.coords.longitude;
  var latlong = {"lat" : lat , "long" : long};
  var latlong_encoded = JSON.stringify(latlong);

  $.ajax({
   url: 'PostTest.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {"userLocation" : latlong_encoded},
   success: function(data) {
        alert(latlong_encoded);
   }
});

}

function errorFunction(position) {
  alert('Error!');
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
$lat[]= array('coord'=>json_decode($_POST["userLocation"]));
print_r($lat);
?>
```

I just get an empty array. 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [coord] => ) )

Comment: "The Php won't retrieve the data" How?

Comment: The javascript is OK - the problem is either in `Dataprocessing.php`, or, if this is `DataProcessing.php` you have incorrectly assumed that posting to `DataProcessing.php` will subsequently result in the snippet of php at the bottom doing anything at all

Comment: I have tried both ways. Originally there were two different scripts where the php was Data Processing.php. Since that didnt work I tried putting it all in one script. I guess that was the wrong approach. Neither worked though,

Comment: In your PHP you're defining $lat as an array twice. Remove the [] from $lat

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
dataType: "json" //for response
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8" //for request
```

in ajax request..

My snippet:

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
    }
    else { 
    alert('Geolocation non supported..');
    }

    function showLocation(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        $.ajax({
           //YOUR AJAX REQUEST USING LAT, LONG
        });
    }
```

Comment: Still not working. When I added the dataType the success function alert no longer appears.

Comment: then try adding contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8" instead.

Comment: the success function works now but the Php doesnt seem to receive it. Is there something in the php settings that needs to be changed?

Comment: Did you removed [] from $lat ?
Do console say something?
Check if data is sended to php (network tab in chrome developer tools).

Comment: There is no error in the console and yes i did remove the [ ]